# Styling Checkbox Buttons using jQuery and Boostrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am using asp.net webform and trying to make my checkbox look like this:

http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/jquery-checkbox-buttons

[image]

I trying to copy the html and js code from above link to my page but it is not working, probably missing CSS and such...

What do I need to add to my page to have the check-boxes look like the pic above, can someone give a full example (included html, css and script)?

This is the code from the link above: it is even working on here: http://jsfiddle.net/DcYhf/65/

But I copy it to my page it is not working anymore...

HTML

```
<span class="button-checkbox">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-lg" data-color="primary">Primary</button>
        <input type="checkbox" class="hidden" checked />
    </span>
```

JS

```
$(function () {
    $('.button-checkbox').each(function () {

        // Settings
        var $widget = $(this),
            $button = $widget.find('button'),
            $checkbox = $widget.find('input:checkbox'),
            color = $button.data('color'),
            settings = {
                on: {
                    icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-check'
                },
                off: {
                    icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked'
                }
            };

        // Event Handlers
        $button.on('click', function () {
            $checkbox.prop('checked', !$checkbox.is(':checked'));
            $checkbox.triggerHandler('change');
            updateDisplay();
        });
        $checkbox.on('change', function () {
            updateDisplay();
        });

        // Actions
        function updateDisplay() {
            var isChecked = $checkbox.is(':checked');

            // Set the button's state
            $button.data('state', (isChecked) ? "on" : "off");

            // Set the button's icon
            $button.find('.state-icon')
                .removeClass()
                .addClass('state-icon ' + settings[$button.data('state')].icon);

            // Update the button's color
            if (isChecked) {
                $button
                    .removeClass('btn-default')
                    .addClass('btn-' + color + ' active');
            }
            else {
                $button
                    .removeClass('btn-' + color + ' active')
                    .addClass('btn-default');
            }
        }

        // Initialization
        function init() {

            updateDisplay();

            // Inject the icon if applicable
            if ($button.find('.state-icon').length == 0) {
                $button.prepend('<i class="state-icon ' + settings[$button.data('state')].icon + '"></i> ');
            }
        }
        init();
    });
});
```

This is what I have now:

[image]

Comment: I think there is a working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/ivawzh/DcYhf/4/

Comment: @Legends It is working here: http://jsfiddle.net/DcYhf/65/ But how do I make it work on my webform, what reference needed?

Comment: look at the top section of the HTML part, there are all references.
To protect myself, I don't know if jQuer UI is really needed, check that out by yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a working example:

```js
$(function () {
    $('.button-checkbox').each(function () {

        // Settings
        var $widget = $(this),
            $button = $widget.find('button'),
            $checkbox = $widget.find('input:checkbox'),
            color = $button.data('color'),
            settings = {
                on: {
                    icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-check'
                },
                off: {
                    icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-unchecked'
                }
            };

        // Event Handlers
        $button.on('click', function () {
            $checkbox.prop('checked', !$checkbox.is(':checked'));
            $checkbox.triggerHandler('change');
            updateDisplay();
        });
        $checkbox.on('change', function () {
            updateDisplay();
        });

        // Actions
        function updateDisplay() {
            var isChecked = $checkbox.is(':checked');

            // Set the button's state
            $button.data('state', (isChecked) ? "on" : "off");

            // Set the button's icon
            $button.find('.state-icon')
                .removeClass()
                .addClass('state-icon ' + settings[$button.data('state')].icon);

            // Update the button's color
            if (isChecked) {
                $button
                    .removeClass('btn-default')
                    .addClass('btn-' + color + ' active');
            }
            else {
                $button
                    .removeClass('btn-' + color + ' active')
                    .addClass('btn-default');
            }
        }

        // Initialization
        function init() {

            updateDisplay();

            // Inject the icon if applicable
            if ($button.find('.state-icon').length === 0) {
                $button.prepend('<i class="state-icon ' + settings[$button.data('state')].icon + '"></i> ');
            }
        }
        init();
    });
});





var     new_checkbox_button = function(name,id){
            return "<li><span class='button-checkbox'><button type='button' class='btn btn-sm btn-primary active' data-color='primary'><i class='state-icon glyphicon glyphicon-check'></i>&nbsp;"+name+"</button><input type='checkbox' class='hidden' checked=''></span></li>";
        };

$("#add").click(function(){
       $("#selected_targets").append(new_checkbox_button("lallalala","1111"));
});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p> Existing checkboxes</p>

    <span class="button-checkbox">
        <button type="button" class="btn" data-color="default">Default</button>
        <input type="checkbox" class="hidden" checked />
    </span>
    <span class="button-checkbox">
        <button type="button" class="btn" data-color="primary">Primary</button>
        <input type="checkbox" class="hidden" checked />
    </span>
    <span class="button-checkbox">
        <button type="button" class="btn" data-color="success">Success</button>
        <input type="checkbox" class="hidden" checked />
    </span>
    <span class="button-checkbox">
        <button type="button" class="btn" data-color="info">Info</button>
        <input type="checkbox" class="hidden" checked />
    </span>
    <span class="button-checkbox">
        <button type="button" class="btn" data-color="warning">Warning</button>
        <input type="checkbox" class="hidden" checked />
    </span>
    <span class="button-checkbox">
        <button type="button" class="btn" data-color="danger">Danger</button>
        <input type="checkbox" class="hidden" checked />
    </span>
    <span class="button-checkbox">
        <button type="button" class="btn" data-color="link">Link</button>
        <input type="checkbox" class="hidden" checked />
    </span>
<br/><br/><br/>
<p> New checkboxes</p>
<button id="add">click to add checkbox</button>
<ui id="selected_targets"></ui>
```

Comment: I need help, how do I make this work with RADIO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29616129

Comment: I am stuck again with Jquery, need help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29681835