# Customize jQuery On-Screen Keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, virtual-keyboard

[image]

I need to display a virtual keyboard in some pages on my web-app, so I found this beautiful jQuery On-Screen Keyboard: http://www.jquery4u.com/demos/onscreenkeyboard/

You can download it from Github: https://github.com/sdeering/onscreenkeyboard/archive/master.zip

I need help to customize it, initially I thought that change CSS will do but turn out it need to be changed on some Jquery functions, I tried removing and changing the order of some functions but didn't work, I dont know Jquery so I am stuck.

For example here are some modifications I need to archive:

- Display upper key by default (right now it displays lower key) and don't give them the option key to turn on lower key.
- Remove Enter key

Can someone help me to figure out those 2 modifications above and give a brief explanation so I can get started and understand how to customize a key, I need a lot of modifications.

Comment: You might want to also check out [this virtual keyboard](http://mottie.github.io/Keyboard/)... It should be much easier to customize and use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Display upper key by default

Add this code to your HTML document (AFTER it loads jquery, which it does on line 113)
What this does is run the changeToCapitalLetter function, which will change the keyboard to the capital keys.

`<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        jsKeyboard.changeToCapitalLetter();
    });
</script>`

> Remove Enter key and don't give them the option key to turn on lower
>   key.

replace lines 177 and 179 with the following code

```
{ value: "", isChar: "false", buttonClass: "button button_empty", keyClass: "key key_empty" },
```

[image: Finished product]

Comment: Thanks a lot! how to make those empty keys disappear (they are still taking place which is fine in order to not messing up the layout, I just don't need them to show up)

Comment: I tried using CSS for it, but it seems that that isn't working for some reason, I'll try to see if I can do anything with the jQuery, but I have no experience at all with jQuery/js.

Comment: I try to add come css for `button_empty` class (tried to make shadow, radius and gradient to become WHITE) but still can't make it invisible, did you have any luck with that?

Comment: No luck yet, tried using jQuery's [.hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/)  function, but it doesn't seem to work (or I might be doing it wrong), and a few more experiments, but no luck at all, I'll continue doing some research soon.

Comment: Well I give up, sorry :P, I just don't understand how javascript/jQuery works, and the weird problem is that it isn't picking up the css classes for some reason.

Comment: no worry I got it work with CSS :)), basically you use the css from `.button` class from beginning till before the /*box shadow*/ for the `button-empty` that will make an invisible button :))

Comment: @Problem: no cursor in chrome because it lost focus when you hitting the keys, so on of those JS events like keyup, keydown, keypress, onfocus... won't work, you know how to fix?